# When does hibernate removes detached object from memory | NonUniqueObjectException

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I understand that when does NonUniqueObjectException occurs and why does it occurs.

I saw many example on the internet for NonUniqueObjectException , each has same thing. 
object is first detached from session1 so session1 is closed and cleared also  and then object with same identifier is update or SaveorUpdate in session2.

Code snippet:

```
 Session session = sessionFactory1.openSession();
 Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
 Item item = (Item) session.get(Item.class, new Long(1234));
 tx.commit();
 session.close(); // end of first session, item is detached   
 item.getId();// The database identity is "1234" item.setDescription("my new description");
 Session session2 = sessionFactory.openSession();
 Transaction tx2 = session2.beginTransaction();
 Item item2 = (Item) session2.get(Item.class, new Long(1234));
 session2.update(item);// Throws NonUniqueObjectException 
 tx2.commit();
 session2.close();
```

My question is even if seesion1 is closed , why does hibernate keeps detached object in session1 though not managing it. when does all the object be removed from session1.

Comment: Please copy the code you are asking about into this question in addition to linking to it (so your question remains intelligible even if that external site goes down, and people don't have to visit an external site to answer your question)

Comment: Added code snippet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hibernate does **not** keep a reference to a detached object, i.e. detached objects are not part of any session, and their garbage collection is not impeded in any way.

The cause of a NonUniqueObjectException is that two different objects for the same database row have become associated with the same session. That's bad because Hibernate automatically detects changes to objects in the session, and writes these changes back to the database. If several objects for the same row are in the same session, it is ambiguous which object's state should be written. Because this would result in hard to find bugs, Hibernate refuses such a situation.

Usually, Hibernate ensures that all queries for a row in a given session return the same object, so this situation can not arise. However, if you use an object obtained from a different session with a new session, it becomes associated with the new session, which can fail if the new session already contains an object for that row.

This is why the newer EntityManager API no longer features an `update` method, that associates a pre-existing object with the session, but a `merge` method, that copies the contents of the object into the object associated with the session.

Answer (score 1):

To understand, have a look here :

[image: http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-katvFbmjewU/Tqv4Ble7_QI/AAAAAAAAAJE/odH15Qm9-hs/s1600/object-states.JPG]

```
 Item item2 = (Item) session2.get(Item.class, new Long(1234));
```

This will turns in persistent state `item2` with id 1234 in the `session2`.

```
session2.update(item);
```

`item` is in detached state, and `update()` will turn `item` in persistent state on `session2` >>> Hibernate throws `NonUniqueObjectException`, because there are two objects `Item` with same id in the same session !

Do it like this :

```
Session session2 = sessionFactory.openSession();
 Transaction tx2 = session2.beginTransaction();
 Item item2 = (Item) session2.get(Item.class, new Long(1234));
 item2.setDescription("my new description");
 session2.update(item2);
 tx2.commit();
```

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong , when I do session1.close() , it will call session1.clear() as well.So if session1 is cleared then hibernate should not find object into memory.  If hibernate is not removing object from memory and just disconnecting session then above behavior is understandable.

Comment: Yeah, but session2 is a new session. session2 doesn't know about `item` object, so it will try to add `item` in database and it will fail... `item` is detached from all session, `item2` is attached to `session2`

Comment: i understand now , so lets assume that GC run after session1.close() , so item will be GCed. Now if session2 tries to update item2  then it should work ?   Can we say that NonUniqueObjectException is on the mercy of GC.

Comment: Good question and no clear idea on that, but `item` cannot be GCed if your code snippet is in the same function. Moreover, `item` is reused after `session1.close()`... Entity objects are GCed when there is no more reference pointing to the object.

Comment: However, in Hibernate Documentation, you can find something about garbage collector : https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html, §10.1. Only transient object are GCed ?!